# How to capture packets off other machine?

Tags: networking, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I want to capture packets from other computers on my network. I have 3 computers in total on same SSID and I want to capture packets off these 2 other computer. How to?

I have tried using wireshark but it only shows packets that being sent to/from my computer not from other computers.

I am using backtrack5.

Answer (score 2):

The 3 computers must be all connected to the same router. Hence, "sharin" packets. Use **Wireshark** and you'll be able to capture packets. Make sure you are connected through a cable to your router, and not via wireless.

Comment: The computer you would like to sniff must be connected to the router through a network cable. However, the computer you're using to read the packets can be connected to the router either wirelessly or through a network cable (you choose).